# CentOS Host serving Ubuntu VM

Tags: networking, ubuntu, virtualbox, centos

Need some help bridging CentOS NIC(physical) to a Ubuntu VM via Virtual-Box's bridging option.

CentOS 7 is running on UCS behind proxy(http/https) environment.
Trying to bridge through that interface so that the VM and the physical interface can be in the same subnet. (I want the physical NIC to act like a switch).

The CentOS host and Ubuntu VM can ping each other. But can't ssh into Ubuntu VM nor can Ubuntu VM ping default gw.

I tried to post as many relevant info as possible below. Thanks as always.

"/etc/sysctl"

```
centos-2 ~]# cat /etc/sysctl.conf 
# System default settings live in /usr/lib/sysctl.d/00-system.conf.
# To override those settings, enter new settings here, or in an /etc/sysctl.d/<name>.conf file
#
# For more information, see sysctl.conf(5) and sysctl.d(5).
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

"ifconfig - Host"

```
centos-2 ~]# ifconfig
enp1s0f0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.27.255.85  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 172.27.255.255
```

"ifconfig - VM"

```
ubuntu ~]# ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.27.255.158  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 172.27.255.255
```

"I can ping"

```
centos-2 ~]# ping 172.27.255.158
PING 172.27.255.158 (172.27.255.158) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.27.255.158: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.705 ms
64 bytes from 172.27.255.158: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.314 ms

ubuntu ~]# ping 172.27.255.85
PING 172.27.255.85 (172.27.255.85) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.27.255.85: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.605 ms
64 bytes from 172.27.255.85: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.914 ms
```

[image: adapter]
Trying to find logs on Linux, etc.
Will update this post with more info as necessary.

Comment: If they can ping one another and ssh is not working then it is probably the firewall (it always can be that sshd is not running). On Ubuntu check if it is listening on port 22 and if the firewall will allow the connection. The ping of the default gateway is working on the host? How are the IPs assigned? Static or DHCP?

Comment: Ubuntu doesn't have ssh installed. I need to do "apt-get" to get that down. Ping of default gw works on CentOS host but not Ubuntu VM. Both host and guest are set static.  UFW/Iptables/Firewallcmd are all disabled on both sides. Do I have to set routing/switching on the Physical NIC or something? (I recall this was easier on Windows).

Comment: Any security set up on UCS? Have you tried with NAT on the VM?

Comment: UCS can have NIC security setup? Need to look up, argh.  I don't want NAT as I want outside world to directly ping/ssh interact with the VM. I basically want the NIC to act like a switch.

Comment: I don't know if UCS has port security :( You will be able to do the same even with NAT you just have to set up VBox Networking with port forwarding. So the port forward to your host can be forwarded to your guest.

Comment: So kind of use it like Docker?  Sharing CentOS host's IP?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36557/discussion-between-zina-and-sndlt).